# print different value from array as expected

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

ERROR:When i print $myconfig array on config.php then it's print a different       value.focus on only [main_url] its value is changed when run on config.php

myconfig.php

```
<?php
        $base_url = $_POST['base_url'];
        if($base_url == ""){
            $url=((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http"). "://". @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/football/responsive_filemanager";
        }else{
            $url=$base_url;
        }   
        echo $base_url."</br>";
        echo $url;

        $myconfig=array(

            'main_url'=>$url,

            'upload_dir' => '/source/',

            'current_path' => '../source/',

            'thumbs_base_path' => '../thumbs/',

            'multiple_selection' => false,

            'multiple_selection_action_button' => false
        );
        //return $myconfig;
        /*echo "<pre>";*/
        //print_r($myconfig);
    ?>
```

Output of myconfig.php
[image]

config.php

```
<?php
     include("../../myconfig.php");
     print_r($myconfig);
     exit();
?>
```

Output of config.php
[image]

Comment: Did you try changing == to !==? Why are you confirming `$base_url` value?

Comment: Yes i try all things.
I confirming $base_url because its value come through ajax or jquery and some time its blank.So i confirming $base_url value

Comment: there is something wrong because `if($base_url == "")` are always false

Comment: I tested both codes.I don't have any problem with them.maybe you put myconfig.php somewhere else and config.php is reading another(maybe test file) file

Comment: Yes thats the error how can i solve bro please help me out i stuck in this problem @Rainmx93

Comment: Can you show me the out as snapshot please.@Mobin F.R.G

Answer (score 1):

I think your condition is wrong. You are setting the value to `$base_url` before your condition, so it will always go in else statement. so if I uderstood your problem your condition should be changed from `$base_url == ""` to `$base_url !== ""`

```
   if($base_url !== ""){
        $url=((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http"). "://". @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/football/responsive_filemanager";
    }
else{
        $url=$base_url;
    }
```

Comment: $base_url value is coming through ajax or jquery